# After getting feedback from interviewer

Tags: interviewing

I got feedback from interviewer that, MD is in vacation and will get back once he is back..

What I have to reply for this mail..

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking this. Assuming they mentioned when the MD will be back from vacation, just

> Thanks for the update.

will do just fine. If not, it would be appropriate to ask *when* the MD will be back.